# Wrangling dataset by picking out Rotten Tomatoes movie ratings from a column

Tags: r, tidyr

I have this sample dataset:

```
structure(list(Title = c("Isn't It Romantic", "Isn't It Romantic", 
"Isn't It Romantic", "Isn't It Romantic", "Isn't It Romantic", 
"Isn't It Romantic", "Gully Boy", "Gully Boy", "Gully Boy", "Gully Boy", 
"Gully Boy", "Gully Boy", "The Wandering Earth", "The Wandering Earth", 
"The Wandering Earth", "The Wandering Earth", "The Wandering Earth", 
"The Wandering Earth", "How to Train Your Dragon: The Hidden World", 
"How to Train Your Dragon: The Hidden World", "How to Train Your Dragon: The Hidden World", 
"How to Train Your Dragon: The Hidden World", "How to Train Your Dragon: The Hidden World", 
"How to Train Your Dragon: The Hidden World", "American Woman", 
"American Woman", "Us", "Us", "Us", "Us", "Us", "Us", "The Wolf's Call", 
"The Wolf's Call", "Avengers: Endgame", "Avengers: Endgame", 
"Avengers: Endgame", "Avengers: Endgame", "Avengers: Endgame", 
"Avengers: Endgame", "The Silence", "The Silence", "The Silence", 
"The Silence", "The Silence", "The Silence", "My Little Pony: Equestria Girls: Spring Breakdown", 
"My Little Pony: Equestria Girls: Spring Breakdown"), Ratings = c("Internet Movie Database", 
"5.9/10", "Rotten Tomatoes", "68%", "Metacritic", "60/100", "Internet Movie Database", 
"8.4/10", "Rotten Tomatoes", "100%", "Metacritic", "65/100", 
"Internet Movie Database", "6.4/10", "Rotten Tomatoes", "74%", 
"Metacritic", "62/100", "Internet Movie Database", "7.6/10", 
"Rotten Tomatoes", "91%", "Metacritic", "71/100", "Rotten Tomatoes", 
"57%", "Internet Movie Database", "7.1/10", "Rotten Tomatoes", 
"94%", "Metacritic", "81/100", "Internet Movie Database", "7.6/10", 
"Internet Movie Database", "8.7/10", "Rotten Tomatoes", "94%", 
"Metacritic", "78/100", "Internet Movie Database", "5.2/10", 
"Rotten Tomatoes", "23%", "Metacritic", "25/100", "Internet Movie Database", 
"7.7/10")), row.names = c(NA, -48L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", 
"data.frame"))
```

[image]

The `Ratings` column has 3 different types of Ratings (Imdb, Rotten Tomatoes and Metacritic) for each movie, spread out over 6 rows for each movie.

I'd like to wrangle this dataset so that for each movie, I create a new column called `rottentomatoes_rating` and the values are the rating. So, in my sample dataset, Isn't it Romantic movie would have 68% under `rottentomatoes_rating`, Gully Boy would have 100% under `rottentomatoes_rating`, etc.

**For those movies that don't have a `rottentomatoes_rating`, then I'd like to put NA under `rottentomatoes_rating`.**

I've thought about using `spread` in tidyr, but I can't quite figure out how to do so since in my case, the variable and values are all in the same column!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming your dataset is called `dt` you can use this process to get a tidy version of your dataset:

```
library(tidyverse)

# specify indexes of Rating companies
ids = seq(1, nrow(dt), 2)

# get rows of Rating companies
dt %>% slice(ids) %>%
  # combine with the rating values
  cbind(dt %>% slice(-ids) %>% select(RatingsValue = Ratings)) %>%
  # reshape dataset
  spread(Ratings, RatingsValue)

#                Title Year     Rated   Released Runtime Internet Movie Database Metacritic Rotten Tomatoes
# 1         Gully Boy 2019 Not Rated 2019-02-14 153 min                  8.4/10     65/100            100%
# 2 Isn't It Romantic 2019     PG-13 2019-02-13  89 min                  5.9/10     60/100             68%
```

Comment: Hey guys, I've edited my sample dataset by including other movies that don't have a Rotten Tomatoes Rating. do you mind having a look at this and adjusting your answer? Currently, your answer doesn't account for movies that don't have a Rotten Tomatoes Rating. Thank you!

Comment: Looks like you haven't tried it yet :) My approach will give you `NA`s wherever you don't have a rating value.

Answer (score 2):

If the data is formatted similarly throughout your dataset, the following code should work:

```
df %>% group_by(Title) %>% 
  slice(match("Rotten Tomatoes", df$Ratings) + 1) %>%
  rename(rottentomatoes_rating = Ratings)
```

This gives:

```
# A tibble: 2 x 6
# Groups:   Title [2]
  Title             Year  Rated     Released   Runtime rottentomatoes_rating
  <chr>             <chr> <chr>     <date>     <chr>   <chr>                
1 Gully Boy         2019  Not Rated 2019-02-14 153 min 100%                 
2 Isn't It Romantic 2019  PG-13     2019-02-13 89 min  68%
```

For the `NA`s, if the original data always has the RT score the row after the string is observed, then it should give you `NA` by default.

Comment: Hey guys, I've edited my sample dataset by including other movies that don't have a Rotten Tomatoes Rating. do you mind having a look at this and adjusting your answer? Currently, your answer doesn't account for movies that don't have a Rotten Tomatoes Rating. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

**sumshyftw** answer is good.

But here is a `data.table` version if you simply want to get rotten tomatoes's percents:

```
dt <- dt[dt$Ratings %like% "%",]
dt <- setnames(dt, "Ratings", "rottentomatoes_rating")
```

Output :

```
# A tibble: 2 x 6
  Title             Year  Rated     Released   Runtime rottentomatoes_rating
  <chr>             <chr> <chr>     <date>     <chr>   <chr>                
1 Isn't It Romantic 2019  PG-13     2019-02-13 89 min  68%                  
2 Gully Boy         2019  Not Rated 2019-02-14 153 min 100%
```

I used `%like% "%"` because I assume that the full data is just like your example.

Comment: Hey guys, I've edited my sample dataset by including other movies that don't have a Rotten Tomatoes Rating. do you mind having a look at this and adjusting your answer? Currently, your answer doesn't account for movies that don't have a Rotten Tomatoes Rating. Thank you!

Comment: @JayBaik Hi, I suggest you use the answer from AntoniosK, it should work perfectly for what you want. It will gives you ``<NA>`` when there is no Rotten Tomatoes value. My data.table version was a simple answer if you or someone would simply want the data where Rotten Tomatoes % is present. Have a good day!

Answer (score 1):

new version that fills NA values when blank

```
# using data.table
library(data.table)
dt <- as.data.table(df)

# Index will hold whether the row is a Provider eg Rotten Tomatoes, or a value
dt[, Index:=rep(c("Provider", "Value"), .N/2)]
# Need an index to bind these together
dt[, Provider.Id:=rep(1:(.N/2), each=2), by=Title]
dt[1:6,]

# segment out the Provider & Values in to columns
out <- dcast(dt, Title+Provider.Id~Index, value.var = "Ratings")
out[, Provider := NULL]

# now convert to full wide format 
out_df <- as.data.frame(dcast(out, Title~Provider, value.var="Value", fill=NA))
out_df
```

Answer (score 0):

To get all metrics with `data.table`

```
# using data.table
library(data.table)
dt <- as.data.table(df)

# groups the data set with by, and extracts the Ratings
# makes use of logic that the odd indeces hold the name of the provider,
# the even ones hold the values. Only works if this holds.
# It can probably be optimised a bit. dcast converts from long to required wide
# format
splitRatings <- function(Ratings){
  # e.g. Ratings=dt$Ratings[1:6]
  N <- length(Ratings)
  split_dt <- data.table(DB=Ratings[1:N %% 2 == 1],
                         Values=Ratings[1-(1:N %% 2) == 1])
  out <- dcast(split_dt, .~DB, value.var = "Values")
  out[, ".":=NULL]
  out
}

# applies the function based on the by clause, returning the table embedded
dt2 <- dt[, splitRatings(Ratings), by=.(Title, Year, Rated, Released, Runtime)]

# convert back
out <- as.data.frame(dt2)
```

Comment: Hey guys, I've edited my sample dataset by including other movies that don't have a Rotten Tomatoes Rating. do you mind having a look at this and adjusting your answer? Currently, your answer doesn't account for movies that don't have a Rotten Tomatoes Rating. Thank you!

Comment: I have something, but will post as a new solution, as it's quite different

Answer (score 0):

Here is one version.

```
df %>% 
  mutate(Value = ifelse(str_detect(Ratings, "\\d"), Ratings, NA)) %>% 
  fill(Value, .direction = "up") %>% 
  filter(!str_detect(Ratings, "\\d")) %>% 
  spread(Ratings, Value)
```